# How do I make my app script code that initially protects one spreadsheet to work for other sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a code that locks/protects all the previously entered cells once the cell in a magic column has been entered. This code works good for just one sheet.
I will want the code functions to extend to all the other sheets in the same file.
Also, the sheets does not have same size, that is some have fewer columns than the other, meaning that the magic columns will be different. The always protected column will also be different.
Please, Is there a way to make it work?, thank you

/**

```
/**
 * Set the values to the desired parameters here; text should always be in quotes;
 * numbers and booleans should never be in quotes
 * 
 * Manually run the installOnEditTrigger() one time, after the first-time set-up
 * of the scripts below in the script editor, for any given spreadsheet file
 * 
 * Only the file owner can change content in protected ranges. If, for any reason
 * (e.g. multiple input errors that the owner does not want to correct by oneself),
 * one wants some earlier rows to become accessible again to all editors =>
 * (1) delete all the rows from the desired row downwards; 
 * (2) go to 'Protect range and sheets' in the 'Data' menu and delete the
 * 'Earlier_Data_Area' protection and the 'Most_Recent_Data_Row(s)'protection (if present);
 * (3) temporarily change the 'hoursToWaitBeforeProtectingLastRow' value below to 0.0003;
 * (4) re-enter (type or copy in again) the value in the last cell of the magic column (may
 * see line 32 below to understand better about the trigger column which 'magic' refers to);
 * this triggers the system to re-protect the present row and all desired upper rows ASAP;
 * (5) change the 'hoursToWaitBeforeProtectingLastRow' value back to the desired value
 * There will now be blank unprotected cells from the desired row downwards
 */

/**
 * Input your desired parameters here
 * Note: This is the only region to edit; only the values after the '=' and before
 * the '//' are to be edited. Strings must be inputed between '' marks, as seen
 * for the examples to be changed; pure numbers are not to be thus enclosed
 */
var sheetToProtect = 'Product Sales'; // The sheet tab name should be enclosed in ''
var startColLetter = 'A'; // The column from which protection should begin; enclose in ''
var endColLetter = 'M'; // The column at which protection should end; enclose in ''
var startRowNumber = 1; // The row number below which all rows till the last filled row of the magic column are to be protected
var magicColumnLetter = 'H'; // The column the cells of which serve as a trigger in a new row for protecting that new row and all other rows above it; enclose in ''
var hoursToWaitBeforeProtectingLastRow = 0.0003; // Note that this is in hours, so 30 min is 0.5 (1.08 sec is 0.0003, to use for testing the script)
let alwaysProtectedPS = ['A3:A', 'I3:J']; // One or more comma-separate ranges which you want to be always protected regardless of the state of other data cells; enclose each range address in ''; simply leave an empty pair of square brackets, [], if there is no range that must always be protected
var fullEditors = ['xxx@gmail.com'] // One or more comma-separate email addresses of users who you want to always have control over all protected ranges; Always include the email addresses of the programmer and the top supervisor
/** End of Inputable Parameters */

/** ------DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT------
 * Establishing the actual working variables
 */
var settings = {};
settings.sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
settings.sheet = settings.sh.getSheetByName(sheetToProtect);
settings.startRow = settings.sheet.getRange(3, startRowNumber, 1, settings.sheet.getLastColumn());
settings.startRowNumber = startRowNumber;
settings.maxRow = settings.sheet.getMaxRows();
settings.lastRow = settings.sheet.getLastRow();
settings.firstColumn = settings.sheet.getRange(startColLetter + ':' + startColLetter).getColumn();
settings.lastColumn = settings.sheet.getRange(endColLetter + ':' + endColLetter).getColumn();
settings.magicColumnNumber = settings.sheet.getRange(magicColumnLetter + ':' + magicColumnLetter).getColumn();
settings.magicColumn = settings.sheet.getRange(1, settings.magicColumnNumber, settings.sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
settings.magicColumnValues = settings.magicColumn.getValues();
settings.magicColumnValues2 = settings.magicColumnValues.flat();
alwaysProtectedPS[0] != '' && alwaysProtectedPS[0] != null && alwaysProtectedPS[0] != undefined ?
  settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range = alwaysProtectedPS.map(e => e) :
  settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range = [];
settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range = '';
settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range != '' ?
  settings.formerFullRowsProtectedRange = settings.sheet.getRange(settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range) :
  settings.formerFullRowsProtectedRange = '';
settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = '';
settings.formerLastFilledMagicRow = '';
settings.latestAreaA1Range = '';
settings.latestAreaA1Range != '' ?
  settings.latestAreaRange = settings.sheet.getRange(settings.latestAreaA1Range) :
  settings.latestAreaRange = '';
settings.latestAreaRangeStartRow = '';
settings.lastFilledMagicRow = ''
settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = '';
settings.editors = fullEditors;

function test() {
  console.log(settings.editors)
}

/**
* Write-prot ects cells in rows above the current row, up till the specified start row when a
* value appears in a magic column in a row lower than the last noted filled row in that magic column.
* Also creates a trigger to protect that new last (filled magic column) row in the sheet, up till the
* last protected row (such that all rows till the specified start row are now protected) when the
* 0.5 hour duration (or one's amended value) has passed since the last edit of the magic column's last row.
*/
function writeProtectRows() {

  // Get row of the last filled cell in the magic column
  settings.lastFilledMagicRow = getLastFilledMagicCellRow_();

  // Start interventions when last magic column cell is edited  
  try {
    var e = settings.sheet.getActiveRange();
    if
      // To be able to capture the edit of the last magic cell, whether it is just the cell itself (uni-cellular edit)
      // or the cell is part of range of cells pasted over (multi-cellular edit)
      ((e.getRow() + e.getHeight() - 1) >= settings.lastFilledMagicRow
      && (e.getColumn() <= settings.magicColumnNumber && (e.getWidth() + e.getColumn() - 1) >= settings.magicColumnNumber)) {

      // Capture the rows that are fully protected before any alterations are done & note the last one
      settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range = formerFullRowProtectedData_(settings.sheet);
      settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = getLastRowNumberOfFormerProtection_(settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range);

      // Get the extra area to protect: usually just the one new row inputted, however, if multiple rows are inputted or there are blanks above the inputted row, there will be multiple rows in the extra area to protect.
      settings.latestAreaA1Range = getExtraAreaToProtect_(settings.lastFilledMagicRow, settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows);

      if (settings.lastFilledMagicRow > settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows) {
        // Remove all range protections from the sheet
        removeProtections_(settings.sheet);

        // Announce rows being immediately protected
        if (settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows !== '') {
          showMessage_('Protecting rows, from ' + settings.startRowNumber +
            ' down to row ' + settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows + '...');
        }

        // Immediately protect the alwaysProtectedPSRange(s) and the formerly fully protected rows (from the specified start row (settings.startRowNumber) till the last row of the rows that were fully protected (settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows))
        if (settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range[0] != ''
          && settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range[0] != null
          && settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range[0] != undefined) {
          for (let i = 0; i < settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range.length; i++) {
            settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range.length == 1 ?
              immediateProtectRows_(settings.sheet.getRange(settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range[i]), 'Always_Protected_Range', settings.editors) :
              immediateProtectRows_(settings.sheet.getRange(settings.alwaysProtectedPSA1Range[i]), 'Always_Protected_Range_' + (i + 1), settings.editors);
          }
        }
        if (settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range != '' && settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range !== null
          && settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range !== undefined) {
          immediateProtectRows_(settings.formerFullRowsProtectedRange, 'Earlier_Data_Area', settings.editors);
        }

        // Install a time-driven trigger that runs the script for protecting the new last row (and any other rows between it and the lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows). It first deletes all ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK triggers.
        if (settings.latestAreaA1Range !== '') {
          showMessage_('Newest added data shall be protected after ' + (hoursToWaitBeforeProtectingLastRow * 60) + ' minute(s)');
          installClockTrigger_('delayedProtectRows_', hoursToWaitBeforeProtectingLastRow);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function getLastFilledMagicCellRow_() {
  try {
    if (settings.maxRow == settings.lastRow) {
      settings.sheet.insertRowAfter(settings.maxRow);
    }
    var lastFilledMagicCellData = settings.sheet
      .getRange(settings.lastRow + 1, settings.magicColumnNumber).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
    settings.lastFilledMagicRow = lastFilledMagicCellData.getRow();
    return settings.lastFilledMagicRow;
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function formerFullRowProtectedData_(sheet) {
  try {
    var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).map(entry => {
      const r = entry.getRange().getA1Notation(); // eg, [ 'D1:D', 'A12:H12', 'A13:H13', 'A2:H11' ]
      let sCol = r.match(/^\D+/);
      let sRow = r.match(/\d+(?=:)/);
      let eCol = r.match(/(?<=:)\D+/);
      let eRow = r.match(/\d+$/);
      return { topRow: sRow == null ? '' : sRow[0], leftCol: sCol == null ? '' : sCol[0], bottomRow: eRow == null ? '' : eRow[0], rightCol: eCol == null ? '' : eCol[0] }
    });

    if (protections.length > 0) { // Proceed only if there are protections
      // Remove entries with empty strings
      const nonEmptyPropertyData = protections.filter(entry => {
        return entry.topRow !== '' && entry.leftCol !== '' && entry.bottomRow !== '' && entry.rightCol !== '';
      });

      if (nonEmptyPropertyData.length > 0) { //Proceed only if there are ranges without infinite parts
        // Convert the Columns to Numbers
        nonEmptyPropertyData.forEach(a => {
          a.leftCol = a.leftCol.charCodeAt() - 64;
          a.rightCol = a.rightCol.charCodeAt() - 64;
        })

        // Find entries whose leftCol match settings.firstColumn AND whose rightCol match settings.lastColumn
        const selectedEntries = nonEmptyPropertyData.filter(entry => {
          return entry.leftCol == settings.firstColumn && entry.rightCol == settings.lastColumn;
        })

        if (selectedEntries[0] !== undefined) { // Proceed only if columnwise end-to-end protected rows exist
          // Convert the bottomRow text values to their numbers
          selectedEntries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.bottomRow = Number(entry.bottomRow);
          })

          // Find biggest bottomRow from the selected entries
          let maxBottomRow = null;
          selectedEntries.forEach(entry => {
            if (maxBottomRow === null || entry.bottomRow > maxBottomRow) {
              //let t = maxBottomRow;
              maxBottomRow = entry.bottomRow;
              return maxBottomRow;
            }
          });

          settings.formerLastFilledMagicRow = maxBottomRow;
          settings.formerFullRowsProtectedRange = settings.sheet.getRange(settings.startRowNumber, settings.firstColumn,
            settings.formerLastFilledMagicRow - settings.startRowNumber + 1, settings.lastColumn);
          settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range = settings.formerFullRowsProtectedRange.getA1Notation();

          return settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function getLastRowNumberOfFormerProtection_(formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range) {
  try {
    formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range != '' && formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range != undefined && formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range != null ?
      settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = Number(formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range.match(/\d+$/)[0]) :
      settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = '';

    return settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows;
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function getExtraAreaToProtect_(lastFilledMagicRow, lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows) {
  try {
    if (lastFilledMagicRow > lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows) {
      lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows !== '' ?
        settings.latestAreaRangeStartRow = settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows + 1 :
        settings.latestAreaRangeStartRow = settings.startRowNumber;
      settings.latestAreaRange = settings.sheet.getRange(settings.latestAreaRangeStartRow, settings.firstColumn, settings.lastFilledMagicRow - settings.latestAreaRangeStartRow + 1, settings.lastColumn);
      settings.latestAreaA1Range = settings.latestAreaRange.getA1Notation();
      return settings.latestAreaA1Range;
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function removeProtections_(sheet) {
  try {
    var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
      var protection = protections[i];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


function immediateProtectRows_(rangeObj, protectionName, editors) {
  try {

    // Define the protections
    let protection = rangeObj.protect().setDescription(protectionName);

    // Protecting the formerdataArea and alwaysProtectedPSRange(s) //formerly, var me = Session.getEffectiveUser(); protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    for (const editor of editors) {
      protection.addEditor(editor);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Protect rows', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}


/**
* Installs a time-driven trigger to run functionName when waitHours have passed from now.
* Deletes any previous instances of CLOCK triggers.
* To review the installed triggers, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
*
* @param {String} functionName The name of the function to run.
* @param {Number} waitHours The number of hours from now when the function should run.
*/
function installClockTrigger_(functionName, waitHours) {
  try {
    deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
      .timeBased()
      .after(waitHours * 60 * 60 * 1000)
      .create();
  } 
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}


/**
* Deletes all installable triggers of the type triggerType associated with the current
* script project that are owned by the current user in the current spreadsheet.
*
* @param {EventType} triggerType One of ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT, .ON_FORM_SUBMIT, .ON_OPEN, .ON_CHANGE, .CLOCK (time-driven triggers) or .ON_EVENT_UPDATED (Calendar events).
*/
function deleteTriggers_(triggerType) {
  try {
    if (triggerType === ScriptApp.EventType.CLOCK) {
      var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    } else {
      triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(settings.sh);
    }
    triggers.forEach(function (trigger) {
      if (trigger.getEventType() === triggerType) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
      }
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}

/**
 * Protect the new range after magic cell is filled, including all rows above till the
 * lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows (or specified start row if lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows is ''
 */
function delayedProtectRows_() {
  try {
    // Retrieving the needed variables (necessary since the time-delayed running made the previously generated ones vanish when the initial onEdit ended)
    settings.lastFilledMagicRow = getLastFilledMagicCellRow_();
    settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range = formerFullRowProtectedData_(settings.sheet);
    settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows = getLastRowNumberOfFormerProtection_(settings.formerFullRowsProtectedA1Range);
    settings.latestAreaA1Range = getExtraAreaToProtect_(settings.lastFilledMagicRow, settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows);
    settings.editors = fullEditors;
    
    // Announce
    let k = '';
    settings.latestAreaRange.getRow !== settings.startRowNumber ?
      k = settings.lastRowNumberOfFormerProtectedFullRows + 1 :
      k = settings.startRowNumber;
    k == settings.lastFilledMagicRow ?
      showMessage_('Protecting row ' + settings.lastFilledMagicRow + ' ...', 6) :
      showMessage_('Protecting rows from ' + k + ' till ' + settings.lastFilledMagicRow + ' ...', 6);

    // Define the protection for latestAreaRange
    let protection2 = settings.latestAreaRange.protect().setDescription('Most_Recent_Data_Row(s)');

    // Protecting the latestAreaRange  //formerly, var me = Session.getEffectiveUser(); protection.addEditor(me);
        protection2.removeEditors(protection2.getEditors());
    if (protection2.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection2.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    for (const editor of settings.editors) {
      protection2.addEditor(editor);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error);
    return "Error: " + error.message;
  }
}

/**
* Installs a trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
* Deletes any previous instances of ON_EDIT triggers.
*
* To permanently install the trigger, choose Run > Run function > installOnEditTrigger.
* You only need to install the trigger once per spreadsheet.
* To review the installed triggers, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
*/
function installOnEditTrigger() {

  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('writeProtectRows')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create();  
}
```